# callback messing with form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Ok so here's what happens..

The user model has a few methods whose functionality depend on the existence of other objects called status_updates which are associated to it in a has_many belongs_to relationship.

So now I realized that the status_updates new page has a form on it, and that controller provides and status_update.build object that is initialized but not saved for that form. Although, when the user method is called from within the view it returns the unsaved initialized value instead of hitting the database to return NilClass.

I fixed that error by putting the following conditions on the user methods that required it.

```
if self.status_updates.count == 0
  temp_status_update
else
  self.status_updates.last
end
```

If there aren't any status_updates for the user object then return an initialized status_update that has default values in it - this status_update won't be saved. it's merely a place holder until a status_update is actually created and saved.

Here's where it gets weird...

Now, when I try to actually save a status_update, it only saves the initialized default values no matter what I submit through the form.

I know that the values are being submitted, it just doesn't seem that these values are making it to the controller.

Here's the actions in my status_updates controller.

```
   def create
      @status_update = current_user.status_updates.build(params[:status_update])
      if @status_update.save
        flash[:success] = "Status Update Saved! #{params[:status_update]}"
      # redirect_to status_update_path(current_user.id)
        redirect_to new_status_update_path
      else
        flash[:error] = "Input Error - Couldn't Save Status Update"
        redirect_to new_status_update_path
      end 
    end  



   def new
     @status_update = current_user.status_updates.build if user_signed_in?
   end
```

Shouldn't the params have the submitted values instead of the default initialized values?

I return the params in the success flash, which returns the correct values to the view.

Here's the status_update model:

```
    class StatusUpdate < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user

      after_initialize :default_values 
      before_create :sanitize 

      #removed stuff from here for brevity

      def default_values
        if self.created_at == nil
          self.current_bf_pct        = 0
          self.current_weight        = 0
          self.current_lbm           = 0    
          self.current_fat_weight    = 0
          self.change_in_weight      = 0 
          self.change_in_bf_pct      = 0
          self.change_in_lbm         = 0
          self.change_in_fat_weight  = 0
          self.total_weight_change   = 0
          self.total_bf_pct_change   = 0
          self.total_lbm_change      = 0
          self.total_fat_change      = 0 
        end
      end

      #removed rest of model from here for brevity
```

here's the user model

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base


      before_create :sanitize

      has_many :status_updates, dependent: :destroy

     #removed stuff from here for brevity

    def sanitize
      #inputs
      self.activity_factor       = 1.3
      self.deficit_amnt          = 1
      self.target_bf_pct         = 10 
      self.fat_factor            = 0.45
      self.protein_factor        = 1
    end

    #Removed functions for brevity


      def temp_status_update
        self.status_updates.build
      end
    end
```

The form I use to submit the status_update

```
        <%= form_for(@status_update) do |f| %>

          <%= f.label :current_weight %>
          <%= f.text_field :current_weight %>

          <%= f.label :current_bf_pct %>
          <%= f.text_field :current_bf_pct %>

          <%= f.submit "Update", class:"btn btn-large btn-primary" %> 
        <% end %>
```

Here are the method calls to the user model from the new status_update view

```
        <tr>
          <td> <%= current_user.current_bf_pct %> % </td>
          <td> <%= current_user.target_bf_pct  %> % </td>
        </tr>
```

Still, the status_update build that is submitted to the create action is stored in the @status_update variable.

Therefore, why is the OTHER status_update build even being considered? It's not being inserted in the variable which is passed to the create action.

Comment: Is my question sufficiently explained, too long, or just incomprehensible? lol How can I ensure other will want to answer my question? I tried to be as clear as I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use default model values in an effort to create a temporary object.

Instead of avoiding the database, just add an attribute to your model called "temporary" and set it to 'true' whenever you create an object that is temporary. Then use find_by_temporary to find it and destroy is as needed.

Answer (score 3):

whenever you want to set attributes after any operation you should set them like this and call that method after_create, after_update etc...

callbacks to model works with all data filled in the database.

```
before_create :sanitize    

def sanitize
self.users.build(user_id, User.current.id, activity_factor:1.3,
  deficit_amnt: 1
  target_bf_pct: 10 
  fat_factor: 0.45
  protein_factor: 1)
end
```

do same for any model where you want to update or set values... and it will just call that method from controller and check them from models so it works.